# Learning - Extensibility: Dynamic loading, and any other no-recompile software updates

Tags: dynamic, extensibility, recompile, extensible

I'm planning on writing a program but I am stuck in a conundrum. I don't want to start writing something and then have to rewrite it all when I find out that my program is not extensible. The other problem, is I do not have enough programming knowledge to know where to begin designing my program so that it is extensible.

I have done some reading on DLLs (or delayed loading for unix), dynamic loading, run-time library loading/deloading, etc.. but I still cannot quite comprehend what I need to do. I will give a sample program example, and if someone could lead me in the right direction for what to learn so my bigger program can begin, I will be extremely grateful!

Let's say I create a console program 'iAmDog' where you can type in commands, and the dog will respond accordingly with output to the console. Now let's assume when I create this program, the dog only has 1 command, 'bark' which produces the output 'roof roof!'. How would I go about writing this program so that while the user is still running the program, I can edit a library, or code somewhere else, to add a 'sit' command to the dogs repertoire.

Again, Ideally my plan is to have *no downtime* or as minimal downtime as possible, all while being able to code updates to functionality of the always running program.

Thank you for reading!

Russell aka SgtPooki

Comment: Any particular reason why it must be no-recompile and not just no-compile? (I.e. Ruby)

Comment: I was mainly asking about C++, guess I should have indicated that, but I was hoping to learn how to do it in C++ based off of the ways other languages do it if nothing came up about C++.  I like C++ =)

Comment: And after learning more about MySQL since posting this, I realize I should be able to accomplish something as simple as command & output. The program would then check for commands in the database instead of having them hardcoded.. but that would leave it very limited to just [ cout << getOutPutFor(userCommand); ] or something similar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using .NET? Then MEF, Managed Extensibility Framework, is probably suited well for you.

There is a [podcast on Hanselminutes about MEF](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=166). You find an mp3 as well as a PDF transcript, that lets you search the show. They even discuss the possibility to continuously watch a folder for updates, to achieve what you descripbe, although they discourage to do this.

Comment: I was planning on using C++ but I thought there may have been some sort of general way to do this for all languages, even if they are a stretch for some.  Why is it not recommended to do this?

Comment: @SgtPooki. I can not remember actually why, but I remember that the discussed that. Have a look into the show.